# Java Array !Not! Out Of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

```
    public class GameEntry {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public GameEntry(String n, int s){
        name = n;
        score = s;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + name + ", "+ score + ")";
    }
}

public class Scoreboard {
    private int numEntries = 0;
    public GameEntry[] board;

    public Scoreboard(int capacity){
        board = new GameEntry[capacity];
    }
    **public void add(GameEntry e){**
        //System.out.println(board[numEntries - 1].getScore());
        int newScore = e.getScore();
        //Is the new entry really a high score


//*****This is the line i refer to as******
        if (numEntries < board.length || newScore > board[numEntries - 1].getScore()) {
            if (numEntries<board.length) {
                numEntries++;
            }
            //shift any lower scores rightward to make room for the new entry
            int j = numEntries - 1;
            while(j>0 && board[j-1].getScore()<newScore){
                board[j] = board[j-1]; //shift entry from j-1 to j
                j--; // and decrement j
            }
            board[j] = e; // when done add a new entry
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to draw your attention inside the Scoreboard class, to its **add** method.

My question is why this code **does not fail**.

The first time the add method runs, the numEntries is equal to 0. So inside the if statement the board[numEntries - 1].getScore should get an IndexOutOfBounds.

When i put it before the if i get the proper exception. Does the if catch the exception?

**I have printed the value of (numEntries - 1) and i get -1. But yet inside the if ot does not seem to bother it.**

The line i refer to is inside the add method the first if.

```
if (numEntries < board.length || newScore > board[numEntries - 1].getScore())
```

Comment: When you first initialize the board array, board[numEntries - 1] still doesn't exist. Meaning, make sure your array has elements before trying to access them.

Comment: numEntries < board.length becomes false second condition is ignored as control will move to else block or out of if

Comment: @ChakradharVyza It's an OR operator, not an AND. So if the first condition is false the second gets checked and NOT ignored.

Comment: my bad cut paste typo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Answer: Short-circuit evaluation of logical *or*.

When the first part of the condition, i.e. `numEntries < board.length` evaluates to `true`, the second part after `||` is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Ok i did not know that. Thanks

Comment: A very common usage of the same mechanism is like that: `if (foo != null && foo.bar())` - it doesn't cause a `NullPointerException` for `foo==null` because the right side of `&&` is not evaluated when the left side evaluates to `false`

Comment: Makes sense to go for the && as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the following expression first:

```
numEntries < board.length
```

Then you have an OR (||) followed by the expression you are asking about.

The compiler checks the expression from left to right. So if the above expression is true, it just enters the if and starts executing it's contents without checking other expressions.